# Iphone storage discrepancy

Tags: iphone, ios

I have an iPhoneXR that I constantly have storage trouble with.
Every time a new iOS update comes out, I run into this issue. I've set it not to download the updates but it seems like it does every time anyways. I try to do the iOS update from my Mac and I see the following.

[image]

[image]

The only solution I've found so far is doing a backup/restore on my entire iPhone, but this gets old having to repeatedly sign into everything again.